# How to get data from another table(join) to DropDownListFor in MVC with SQL Server using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm working on a project ASP.NET MVC.I want to get data from SQL to `@Html.DropDownListFor`.
I get this NullReferenceException:

> `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get` returned null.

I've been looking through this exception detail but can't figure what's causing this exception.

My view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Famille, new SelectList(Model.listfamille, "ID_Famille", "Nom_Famille"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })


    </div>
</div>
```

My model

```
public partial class Article
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Article()
    {
        this.Details_Commande = new HashSet<Details_Commande>();

    }
    public int ID_Article { get; set; }
    public string Nom_Article { get; set; }
    public int Quantite_Article { get; set; }
    public string Prix_Article { get; set; }
    public int ID_Famille { get; set; }
    public int Alert_Article { get; set; }
    public int ID_Fournisseur { get; set; }

    //public virtual Famille Famille { get; set; }
    public virtual Fournisseur Fournisseur { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Details_Commande> Details_Commande { get; set; }
public List<Famille> listfamille { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
  public ActionResult getdata()
    {

        Article article = new Article();
      article.listfamille = ob.Famille
                           .Select(tc => new Famille
                           {
                               ID_Famille = tc.ID_Famille,
                               Nom_Famille = tc.Nom_Famille
                           })
                           .ToList();
        return View(article);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: In your controller you are not getting data from Entity Framework.  You are just creating a new instance of your Article entity.  Since your entity is unpopulated, listfamille is null as it's never been initialized.

Comment: When debugging, Is there any value/data in `article.listfamille`?

Comment: @Bosco,No any value just this  exception " System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null."

Comment: @Sony - Code looks fine, is there actually any data in the Famille table, in the off chance ?

Comment: Yes of course there is data in the Famille table

Answer (score 0):

I've done my best to replicate your scenario/error but have been unable to.  Here is what I did.  If I've made any incorrect assumptions perhaps you could let me know and I will edit my answer.  The code below generates a dropdown without a problem.

Note I don't recommend sending entity framework models to the view.  I would normally use a view model.  This looks like a good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu24lZsUreg) if you don't know what they are.

My models

```
public class Famille
{
    public int ID_Famille { get; set; }
    public string Nom_Famille { get; set; }
} 
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {

    }
    public int ID_Article { get; set; }
    public string Nom_Article { get; set; }
    public int Quantite_Article { get; set; }
    public string Prix_Article { get; set; }
    public int ID_Famille { get; set; }
    public int Alert_Article { get; set; }
    public int ID_Fournisseur { get; set; }
    public List<Famille> listfamille { get; set; }
}
```

My Entity Framework 6.2 DbContext

```
public class MyContext: DbContext       
{
    public DbSet<Famille> Famille { get; set; }
    public MyContext()
        :base("{my connection string}")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {    
        modelBuilder.Entity<Famille>()
             .HasKey(c => c.ID_Famille);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Famille>()
           .ToTable("famille");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult getdata()
    {
        using (var ob = new MyContext())
        {
            Article article = new Article();
            var familles = ob.Famille.ToList();
            article.listfamille = familles;
            return View(article);
        }         
    }  
}
```

getData.cshtml

```
@using Article.Controllers    
@model Article    

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Famille, new SelectList(Model.listfamille, "ID_Famille", "Nom_Famille"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })   
    </div>
</div>
```